# Add information to author

Tags: bibtex

I want to specify additional information (such as the university) for an author:

```
author = {Some Author (Some University)},
```

However this compiles to:

> S. A. S. University)

Using `author = {Some Author {(Some University)}},` gives

> S. A. (Some University)

So I could probably use `author = {Some {Author (Some University)}},` but this feels like an awkward workaround. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: No, because the author field is obviously for the names and surnames of authors only, and everything else will be treated as names or surnames. If you group some words will be treated a one author having more than one surname.  Whit respecet elegnace, IMO this workaround is not the real problem, but that you obtained what you are looking for. `:)`

Comment: Edit the bst to add a new university field and then modify the function that creates the names to examine the university field.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? Separately, please explain the use case for wishing to provide information about academic (or other) affiliations when stating the names of the authors of a publication. Are you concerned that readers will be confused about two John Smiths, one at Harvard and other at Yale (just to offer a specific example...), who happen to be publishing in the very same field and happen to have publications with nearly identical titles published in the same journals and years?

Comment: `author = {Author, Some {(Some University)}}`, but I definitely would not recommend it.

Comment: @Mico I use the `ieeetr` style. You're probably right, there's no need to mention the affiliation. The use case was about authors having multiple affiliations and to mention the one the work was done for. But that's probably no important information for a citation (it appears in the referenced work though). However, just out of curiosity, what about your example of two authors with similar names? What would you recommend then?

Comment: If you really have two authors named John Smith (or Anna Carlsen, or...) -- one at Oxford, the other at Cambridge, say -- writing at about the same time, publishing in the same journals, and using nearly identical titles for their works, I suppose you should provide some careful disambiguation in the body of your own paper. E.g., "At Cambridge University, a professor named John Smith claimed that ... Meanwhile, at Oxford, another professor coincidentally also named John Smith wrote that ...".